# Asynchronous Server in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows, async, sockets

We are looking to develop an asynchronous server in C++. We are coming from C#, which has built-in support for async-await networking. However, with C++ it appears as if it is basically mandatory to use [ASIO](https://think-async.com/Asio/), other you're out of luck.

I am wondering if there is are any other options besides ASIO if we want to make an asynchronous server in C++? It would be preferable not to have to rely on a third party library.

Comment: Boost is effectively part of the standard library, no reason to avoid it. In the past, I worked on a project where Boost was not an option due to technical reasons, and used Tntnet which supports an event loop. C++20 integrates language-level support for async/await, but that's useless without a library that provides an executor. All in all, C++ does not have as good async support as C#. If you don't want to use Boost.Asio, you'll probably want to stick to a classic threadpool instead. And have you considered not using C++? E.g. async Rust is also awful, but 1000× better than with C++.

Comment: There is certainly whichever platform-specific library ASIO uses on your platform.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106863/do-all-c-compilers-support-the-async-await-keywords

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/Amanieu/asyncplusplus

Comment: You might find [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with C++ it appears as if it is basically mandatory to use ASIO

not at all. That's just a cross-platform library which gives you nice, portable code.

You can always code directly to your platform APIs (admittedly on Windows I have no idea what those are). Or, you can use [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with futures/promises to wrap synchronous I/O (or `packaged_task` with your own threadpool, or whatever).

The point is there's plenty of code out there doing both asynchronous and non-blocking synchronous multiplexing I/O without using ASIO or Boost.Asio. It's just either platform-specific, or uses another 3rd-party library, or contains an equivalent amount of platform abstraction code internally.

> It would be preferable not to have to rely on a third party library.

From the *language* point of view, your platform APIs *are* 3rd party. Since you definitely need to use *something* that isn't part of the standard library, you might just as well use the nice portable one.

Comment: On Windows it would be I/O Completion Ports. You issue one or more "overlapped" read/write operations and then you call the "wait for something to finish" function (GetQueuedCompletionStatus). Then you process the result of whatever finished, optionally issue more operations, and repeat.